# The frontend(ecs fargate) fails to send a normal request to the backend(fargate) through load balancer in private subnet

Tags: reactjs, terraform, amazon-ecs

I'm building aws cloud with Terraform. There is a problem that is not solved, so I leave a question like this.

Currently, the front-end (react) and the back-end (fastapi) are **ecs fargate**, each creating a cluster on a **private subnet** separately.
Traffic coming from an Internet gateway is designed to enter the front-end through a load balancer and then, distribute the traffic back to the back-end through a load balancer in a private subnet.
So **I applied the domain of the load balancer to the host at the front-end**, and the **domain of the load balancer** was specified **in the environment variable of the ecs task at the front end.**
but The front-end fails to send a normal request to the back-end. It occurs 405 errors.
Below is the *fron-end ecs task definition in terraform.*

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "react" {
  family                   = "react"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = 1024
  memory                   = 4096
  execution_role_arn       = "${aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.arn}"
  task_role_arn            = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_execution_role.arn}"
  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
[
  {
    "image": "<image pulled from ecs>",
    "cpu": 1024,
    "memory": 4096,
    "name": "react",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 80,
        "hostPort": 80
      }
    ],
    "environment": [
    {
        "name": "REACT_APP_HOST",
        "value": ${jsonencode(local.domain)}
    }
    ]
  }
]
DEFINITION
}
```

*local.domain* is specified like this.

```
locals {
  domain = "${var.var_http}${aws_lb.fastapi.dns_name}"  
}
```

**and I tried..**

When I connect the domain of the load balancer to the local front-end, I have confirmed that it works normally.
When setting up the domain of react, I thought react might not have read the domain of the load balancer, so I installed env-cmd as npm in the docker file I uploaded with react in ecr, and I installed scripts as `"build": "env-cmd -f.I tried to modify to env react-scripts build"`, but an error occurred in the docker file.

thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is a web browser javascript framework. React runs in the browser. Your front-end Fargate server isn't doing anything but serving up static files to web browsers. The code is running in each user's web browser. The API requests to the back end are not coming from the front-end Fargate server, they are coming from each user's laptop/desktop computer. In order for that code, running in people's web browsers, to access your back-end API, the API has to be available publicly on the Internet.

Comment: Thank you, do you mean that security group inbound in backend api should be set to allow all IPs? Security groups are already set up as follows.
Both inbound and outbound are open on port 80. and cidr_blocks is set [0.0.0.0/0]

Comment: You said the load balancer for the backend was in a private subnet. That would prevent it from being accessed over the Internet.